# How to access authenticated user out of controller context

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a question regarding access to the logged in user, when following the Nest.js guide on authentication (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication). I'm using mongoose as my database driver, and all my data is persisted to MongoDB (user data as well). I want to have "createdBy" and "updatedBy" fields on each document saved or updated in the database.

This can be done by adding these during the schema.pre('save', function() {}) callback, when defining the schema. But I have no way to access the current user performing the save action. The current logged in user is saved in request after the request passes the jwt auth guard.

How do I get a hold of this user at the point of the schema.pre('save') callback?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new User decorator to do what you need.

```
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator((data, req) => req.user);
```

Then in your controllers you can just use it like a parameter like below

```
@Get()
  async getAll(@User() user: UserModel): Promise<Client[]> {
    return this.clientService.getAll(user._id);
  }
```

Comment: More information can be found here in the docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)